# Change dataset of multiple DOM Elements without having to loop

Tags: javascript

I have `n` DOM Elements that has the same `dataset` structure,
I'd like to link them so when I'll update the `dataset`, each linked element would update its own as well.

I tried using the `dataset` object as a reference for all elements, but it doesn't work since `dataset` **is a read only property**.
As of right now I'm looping on each element and change its `dataset`.

On the other hand I read in so many stackoverflow answers that claim it could be done, but never mention how..
and since my reputation is low I can't contact them directly..

Comment: Each element has it's own `dataset` view into the internal map of `data-` attributes. The fact that they all have the same set of `data-` attributes does not change that.

Comment: Objects can't really be "linked" like that, but you can use a [DOM Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) so that when one changes, you can have code automatically fire that would then loop over the others and change them, but you will have to loop. There's no getting around that.